# How to design an update SP that allows both setting columns to null and leaving columns unchanged

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a table called `Customer` with a primary key and data columns such as `Name` and `DateOfBirth`.  I want to write a SP called `UpdCustomerByKey` that takes parameters `CustomerKey`, `Name` and `DateOfBirth`.

The `CustomerKey` parameter would be required but the data parameters would be optional.  If they are not supplied, the column should be left unchanged.

Usually, this is done with something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdCustomer]
(
    @CustomerKey BIGINT,
    @Name NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @DateOfBirth DATETIME = NULL
) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customer SET
        Name = ISNULL(@Name, Name),
        DateOfBirth = ISNULL(@DateOfBirth, DateOfBirth)
    WHERE CustomerKey = @CustomerKey
END
```

This way

```
UpdCustomer @CustomerKey=123, @DateOfBirth='2000-05-12'
```

will update `DateOfBirth` while leaving `Name` unchanged.

The problem with this design is that it doesn't let the caller set data columns to `NULL`. If I tried to set `DateOfBirth` to `NULL` like this:

```
UpdCustomer @CustomerKey=123, @DateOfBirth=NULL
```

instead of setting `DateOfBirth` to `NULL`, it would leave that column unchanged.

How do I keep this basic design but allow setting columns to `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use default values for the parameters that wouldn't be sent in otherwise. `NULL` is a valid use case for you, so it can't be `NULL`. But perhaps empty string and the minimum `DATETIME` value would work for you, like so?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdCustomer]
(
    @CustomerKey BIGINT,
    @Name NVARCHAR(100) = '',
    @DateOfBirth DATETIME = '1753-01-01'
) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customer SET
        Name = IIF(@Name = '', Name, @Name),
        DateOfBirth = IIF(@DateOfBirth = '1753-01-01', DateOfBirth, @DateOfBirth)
    WHERE CustomerKey = @CustomerKey
END
```

Comment: Is there any way to get '1753-01-01' without specifying it explicitly (such as by calling a function)?

Comment: @JoelFan For the parameter's definition inside the procedure or when you make a call to execute the procedure?

Comment: from inside the procedure (you don't need it for executing the procedure, just leave out the @DateOfBirth parameter)

Comment: @JoelFan Nah, unfortunately the parameters in the definition of a procedure can only be defaulted to literal values.

Answer (score 1):

- One way is to make `@Name` and `@DateOfBirth` parameters mandatory, using get and set approach. Get the existing and set or unset as you need.

  ```
  CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdCustomer]
  (
      @CustomerKey BIGINT,
      @Name NVARCHAR(100),
      @DateOfBirth DATETIME
    ) AS
    BEGIN
       UPDATE Customers SET
          Name = @Name,
          DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth
       WHERE CustomerKey = @CustomerKey
    END
  ```

  Caller has to set them all, either `NULL` or `NOT NULL`,

  ```
  EXEC [UpdCustomer] @CustomerKey = 1, @Name=NULL, @DateOfBirth = NULL
  GO

  EXEC [UpdCustomer] @CustomerKey = 1, @Name='Name01', @DateOfBirth = NULL
  GO

  EXEC [UpdCustomer] @CustomerKey = 2, @Name='Name02', @DateOfBirth = '01-31-2024'
  GO
  ```
- If you could split them to two calls, then two different procs is best.

  ```
  CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdCustomerName]
  (
       @CustomerKey BIGINT,
       @Name NVARCHAR(100)= NULL
  ) AS
  BEGIN
       UPDATE Customers SET
           Name = @Name
       WHERE CustomerKey = @CustomerKey
  END
  ```

  ```
  CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdCustomerDateOfBirth]
  (
       @CustomerKey BIGINT,
       @DateOfBirth DATETIME = NULL
  ) AS
  BEGIN
       UPDATE Customers SET
           DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth
       WHERE CustomerKey = @CustomerKey
  END
  ```
- The last option would be handling them with dynamic sql in single proc.

Comment: I don't want a solution where I have to make more than 1 SP call writing to the same row. That's a performance hit and increases risks of deadlocks

Comment: I think @J.D.s solution works your case, if you are ok with unused defaults.

Comment: This does not address the question, which specifically asked to "keep this basic design", namely a single SP that can update multiple columns, leaving out columns that should be left unchanged. Suggesting a separate SP for every column, or a single SP where every column value must be specified, are not relevant to the question.

Comment: @JoelFan While I acknowledge that the proposed options may not appear as potential solutions for your issue, they certainly address the problem you've raised. As for maintaining the basic design, the procedure parameters, update statement, and caller calls are all variables. I believe it's challenging to find solution without making alterations to any of these components.